# Tool to generate sitemap from list of links?

Tags: generator, sitemap

I have a list of links for our site that point to my local dev environment. I need to make a valid sitemap according to the protocol here. http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php

I have created an initial version by hand that validates as XML, however, when I feed it into the Dustme Selectors Firefox extension, I am told that it is invalid.

I can't seem to find any tool online that will validate my sitemap via direct entry. They all ask for a URL to be pointed to. Plus they would all fail anyway because the URLs are not publicly accessible.

Does anyone know of a tool (online or not) that will accept direct input and either generate a sitemap from a list of URLs or at least validate the XML document that I have created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just validate it against the XML schemas, as described here

http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#validating

Answer (score -1):

You can use http://www.timestampgenerator.com/tools/xml-sitemap-from-list/
And after that make some changes with the help of text editor